# Detecting availability of SVG?

Tags: elisp, gui-emacs

For a few years Emacs has had SVG support, however I don't know of a reliable way to detect it, before using it.

How can we detect in EmacsLisp, SVG rendering ability in the current Emacs GUI (X/NS/Mac/Win etc.)

It's not sufficient to assume a GUI build has SVG support, as this is not always the case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe some clue in 'image.el'..

C-h v image-type-available-p

> image-type-available-p is an autoloaded compiled Lisp function in
>   `image.el'.
>
> (image-type-available-p TYPE)
>
> Return non-nil if image type TYPE is available. Image types are
>   symbols like `xbm' or `jpeg'.

Comment: Specifically `(image-type-available-p 'svg)` - Thank you!