# SVG rendering in Org Mode - Emacs 28.1 on Windows 10

Tags: org-mode, microsoft-windows, inline-image, svg

When rendering a SVG image in Org mode, it shows a colored rectangle.
Used `org-toggle-inline-images` to show the image.

[image]

Ok... now downloading [this image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e8/Svg_example3.svg), it gets correctly rendered by Emacs and in an Org-mode file:

[image]

`(image-type-available-p 'svg)` returns `t` (See [Detecting availability of SVG?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10908/detecting-availability-of-svg)).

So... why the first SVG image is not correctly shown?
It is perfectly shown in other apps like Chrome browser.

Comment: Is your Emacs built with SVG support? Download an SVG from the web and try to open it in Emacs with `C-x C-f`. If you cannot see the image, then your Emacs does not support SVG. If you can, then further debugging is warranted. Please post your findings *in your question*, not as a comment.

Comment: So what happens when you open the image with `C-x C-f`? Do you see it or do you see the rectangle? IOW, the question is: is the problem with Emacs displaying SVG files or is the problem with Org mode toggling inline images? Does a PNG image work (try it both ways)?

Comment: Something wrong with the image perhaps? Different apps have different tolerances for problems in the file: Chrome may be tolerant but the SVG library on your system may not be. You can pastebin the image somewhere and let people try it out.

Comment: It seem that the SVG image not showing has JPEG inside encoded in base64. Not sure if that could be the cause that Emacs is not rendering it.

Comment: It could be or it could be something else. Where did you get the broken SVG? If it's up on the Web, can you provide a URL? We can then test it independently.

Comment: Unfortunately, can't provide it because it was generated by other person in the company, and it is confidential... Sorry!

Comment: Ok - unless somebody constructs such an SVG file, that leaves no options for outsiders to help.